# Error while launching meteor after upgraded to the last version 1.2.1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have upgraded meteor to the latest version and something was broken.

I get this error when launching meteor :

```
W20151027-19:59:16.814(0)? (STDERR) 
W20151027-19:59:16.814(0)? (STDERR) /Users/dev/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1xbrzvw++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt- os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151027-19:59:16.815(0)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20151027-19:59:16.815(0)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20151027-19:59:16.942(0)? (STDERR) Error: deny: Value for `update` must be a function
W20151027-19:59:16.942(0)? (STDERR)     at packages/mongo/collection.js:755:1
W20151027-19:59:16.942(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (packages/es5-shim/.npm/package/node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js:417:1)
W20151027-19:59:16.942(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
W20151027-19:59:16.942(0)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].addValidator (packages/mongo/collection.js:752:1)
W20151027-19:59:16.943(0)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.deny (packages/mongo/collection.js:804:1)
W20151027-19:59:16.943(0)? (STDERR)     at Posts.getNotificationProperties.properties.postAuthorName (lib/herald.js:7:21)
W20151027-19:59:16.943(0)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dev/Desktop/akhbar/danzo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:249:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hey, did u solved this issue?

Comment: @Saidh  replaces - lines by +
 Herald.collection.deny({
-    update: !Users.can.editById,
-    remove: !Users.can.editById
+    update: function(){ return !Users.can.editById; },
+    remove: function(){ return !Users.can.editById; }
   });

Comment: Yeah, I just did it, and worked. Thanks. Initially couldn't find the file to be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [release notes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/bfdf975eedbf6bc87af644492eb2ea258a6f5fe7/History.md#v121-2015-oct-26):

> Collection#allow/deny now throw errors when passed falsy values. [#5442](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/5442)